# Speex for iphone

Tags: iphone, audio, speex

how to use "speex" for audio encoding/decoding in iphone? I am not getting the framework to add in project.

Answer (score 5):

This [blog entry: Compile Speex For iPhone](http://codeforfun.wordpress.com/2010/04/29/compile-speex-for-iphone/) by Clifton Craig should be helpful. Be warned though that I haven't tried this myself.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone stumbling across this old thread: Yes Speex runs on the Phone. You have to copy in libogg and libspeex source folders to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty vague, but you may wish to read [this thread](http://lists.xiph.org/pipermail/speex-dev/2008-November/006978.html), where they claim to have Speex working in realtime on the iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Disclosure: I am the developer and this is not a free solution, unlike [Cliff's great post](http://codeforfun.wordpress.com/2010/04/29/compile-speex-for-iphone/) that [alan-p references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3300017).

That said, [SpeexKit](http://www.politepix.com/speexkit) is a framework for doing file-based and buffer-based Speex encoding and decoding wrapped in Objective-C methods.